# How can I programatically check that I am running Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

How can I programatically check that I am running Windows 8.1 using cmd.exe or PowerShell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Powershell

`get-wmiobject win32_operatingsystem` will return several properties you can use to check the OS.

```
get-wmiobject win32_operatingsystem|select-object name,caption,buildnumber,version|format-list

name        : Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise|C:\WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition2
caption     : Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise
buildnumber : 9600
version     : 6.3.9600
```

Comment: Interesting that we need to use `win32_operatingsystem` on a 64bit operating system.

Comment: The class-names wasn't changed due to compatibility reasons. `Win64_*` names for 64bit os would just add complexity without giving any benefits.

Answer (score 2):

**CMD**

```
wmic os get caption /value|find "="
```

to put it into a variable:

```
for /f %%i in ('wmic os get caption /value^|find "="') do set version=%%i
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method using PowerShell:

```
(Get-Command -Name $env:windir\system32\ntoskrnl.exe).FileVersionInfo.FileVersion -match '6.3.9600';
```

This command returns `$true` or `$false`. To be honest, alroc's is the ideal solution, in my opinion. This is just an alternative.